# Test class coverage issue

Tags: unit-test, controller, class, wrapper-class

The test class below is covering the class successfully but I am getting difficulty to cover my wrapper list.

**Coverage**

[image: Coverage Screenshot]

I added data for `lstPayslip` in test class. I want to cover `listWrapper`. Getting trouble here.

my test class is as follows:

```
@isTest
public class DisplayPayslipControllerTest {

    //Global Variables
    private static Payslip__c objPayslip;
    private static List<Payslip__c> listPayslip;
    private static Employee__c objEmployee;
    private static Boolean Bool;

    //Data to test
    @testSetup
    public static void testData() {

        listPayslip=new List<Payslip__c>();
        objEmployee=new Employee__c(Name='TestOne',Password__c='Set@123',Mobile_Number__c='9876534563',
                                    Tech_Official_Email_ID__c='samruddhipode.techila@gmail.com');
        insert objEmployee;

        objPayslip=new Payslip__c(Total_Attendence__c=30,Last_Sent_Date1__c=system.now(),Sent_Date__c=system.now(),
                                  Other_Deduction__c=2000,ESIC_Monthly__c=2000,Techila_Variable__c=200,C_A__c=3000,
                                  Leave_Encashment__c=500,TDS_Monthly__c=6000,Advance_Monthly__c=6000,
                                  Opening_Balance__c=2,Leave_Availed__c=1,
                                  Techila_Basic__c=2000,PF_Employee_12_till_date__c=2000,PF_Employer_12_till_date__c=2000,
                                  Monthly_Fixed_HRA__c=5000,Food__c=1000,
                                  Fixed_Education_Allowance__c=1000,
                                  PT_Monthly__c=100,
                                  Techila_Medical_Allowance__c=3000,
                                  Monthly_PF__c=200,
                                  Techila_Year__c='2016',
                                  For_the_Month__c='JAN',Employee__c=objEmployee.id
                                // Id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
                                 );
      //  insert objPayslip;  
        system.debug('objPayslip------------->'+objPayslip);
        listPayslip.add(objPayslip);
    }

    public static testmethod void mthdDisplayPayslip() {

        testData();
        insert listPayslip;
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', objPayslip.Id);

         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(objPayslip); 

        //Instance of controller
           DisplayPayslipController objPaySend = new DisplayPayslipController(sc);        
           objPaySend.getrecords(); 
          // objPaySend.selectAll();          
           objPaySend.send();
           DisplayPayslipController.WrapperClass objWrapperClass=new DisplayPayslipController.WrapperClass(objPayslip,false);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include relevant controller code as text as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the either strSelected or strSelected1 to a non-blank, non-null value before you call your method:

```
objPaySend.strSelected = 'Hello World';
objPaySend.getRecords();
```

Make sure that the strSelected or strSelected1 variable matches the payslip record you created.

Side notes:

You can use `String.isNotBlank(strSelected)` instead of `strSelected != null && strSelected != ''`. It's a bit easier to read and quite a bit shorter, too.

You don't need to check if the list is empty before you iterate over an empty list. You can delete lines 90 and 94.

Action methods can use the `void` return type instead of using `return null`. More experienced developers tend to expect that a method might be capable of redirecting if a PageReference return type is used. This would also eliminate the need for line 96.

Change:

```
public PageReference getRecords() {
```

To:

```
public void getRecords() {
```

Comment: Thank you so much sfdcfox. It worked. Thank you for the guidance too since i am a beginner i need that. Now my wrapper list covered successfully but i am getting trouble to cover the send() method. It is the action for sending email to the checked records(checkbox).

Comment: @p.samruddhi I presume it'll be more of the same; you need to populate the list, then set selected to true for one or more wrapper items, then call the send method.